# how to insert data to database using azure function

Tags: html, azure-functions

I have an form page in HTML which collects users basic details. I want to fetch that information and using azure functions i want to store that data into an table.

Any guidence?

Comment: This example uses a timer function, but the SQL connection works the exact same way: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup

Comment: @SamaraSoucy-MSFT thanks for the reply. so basically i have an static HTML page and what i want is that after user fill in the form i want to call this azure function and insert the data that user has entered into this HTML page on button click. Can you help me on this

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store data into storage table, there are [Output bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table#output) to write entities to a table in an Azure Storage account.

And if you want to store data in to sql table. There is a [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup#set-the-connection-string) about how to connect your function with SQL Database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. so basically i have an static HTML page and what i want is that after user fill in the form i want to call this azure function and insert the data that user has entered into this HTML page on button click

Comment: The simplest way to do that is to use two functions- one to serve the page and one to process the form data.